# What is this seven inch long tool?

Tags: tools

What is this?  The metal strip is 7 inches long.  There is a small hook in the end.  The other end is just a plastic handle.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a "puller", for pulling string or cord or wire through things.

That one could be for mattresses or cushions for the "buttons" or similar.

Comment: I assumed that it is a puller but what does it pull?  The mattress idea is interesting.  I will look at that.  Buttons?  like sewing buttons on shirts and jackets?  Then I'm not sure why it would be 7 inches long.  Just saying...

Comment: @LarryGeiger lots of chairs sofas etc have "buttons" on them - leather chairs can have them to give that "dimpled" effect. So, if you think about the thickness of some of the cushioning etc...

Comment: I think it is primarily for leather. Mostly from a time when horses were used and owners would repair or make their own harnesses/tack.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a slim jim auto tool.
A slim jim is used to open certain kinds of car doors by slipping between the glass and the frame of the door and grabbing the latch bar.